# How send a request error inside the save function?

Tags: django, httpresponse

I need to validate the video duration before the video is saved,but he only message error i found is the forms.ValidationError. The upload request is getting error 500 because of the raise.

[image]

```py
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            ...
            result = subprocess.Popen(["ffprobe", video_path],
            stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
            t = [x for x in result.stdout.readlines() if "Duration" in x]
            if duration > 30:
                raise forms.ValidationError('The Video must have 30 secs')
            ...
```

But i need a response instead of raise like:

`return Response({'detail': 'This video must have 30 secs'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)`

But i only know how to use `Response` inside the `Views`, is there a way to use Response inside the save function?

Comment: In your view you can wrap `serializer.save()` or wherever you're calling the save function in a `try/except`

Comment: Thanks i forget this, but i use ry:
            video = super(VideoViewSet, self).create(request)
        except:
            return Response({'detail': 'Video is to big'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)